# RGtensor undefines some symbol

Tags: packages, symbols

I am using the package [RGTC](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/) for differential geometry. 
Firstly I define a symbol `σ = Array[PauliMatrix, {3}];`, then a metric and other stuff (as required by the package)
Then I call the command RGtensor and it undefines my simbol `σ`.
Any idea of why? I think is something defined in the package, but I don't know how to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

The `RGTensors` definition in [the EDCRGTCcode.m file for that package](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/~sbonano/RGTC/) starts as follows:

```
RGtensors[gIN_, xIN_, opt___] := 
 Module[
   {frameOpt = 0, eIN, Ropt = True, Wopt = True, Eopt = True, idMat, eFrame, dxRul, Bmat, 
    Amat, NP$ = False, de, k$, StrCon, γUdd, γddd, g1ddd, g2ddd, Gamddd, rmn, tmp, 
    RUd, Rg, gg, sT, Cflat, EinSp}, 

   Clear[
    GUdd, covD, covDiv, LieD, ωUd, RUddd, Rdddd, Rdd, EUd, 
    R, Wdddd, detg, p$D, rtAbsdetg, eta, HStar, Lower, 
    Raise, τ, κ, ρ, 
    (* Here's the likely culprit *)
    σ, 
    (* ------------------------- *)
    γ, ϵ, α, β, ν, $π, λ, μ, Λ, Ψ, Φ, Δ,
    \[GothicCapitalD], δ, δB
  ]; 

  DEF$covD; 
  DEF$covDiv; 
  .
  .
  .
```

It seems that the first thing that function does is clear a whole lot of non-localized variables (although I would have expected them to be segregated in a non-global context). That might be why any definition of `σ` you make gets cleared...

In fact, the RGTC.nb notebook that is part of that package mentions that "`RGtensors` defines the following global variables:"; now, `σ` is not in the list, but clearly the package was intended to have have side-effects in the `` Global` `` context.